# Not Returnin Data from Database App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My Java Google App Engine Project is not returning data from database and no error is displayed.

Follow´s JSP page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pessoas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<%
PessoaDao dao = PessoaDao.INSTANCE;
List<Pessoa> pessoas;
pessoas = dao.listPessoas();
%>

Numero total de pessoas: <% pessoas.size(); %> Pessoas.

<table>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Idade</th>
</tr>
<%for (Pessoa p : pessoas) {%>
<tr>
<td>
<%p.getNome(); %>
</td>
<td>
<%p.getIdade();  %>
</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Follow my class that return data:

```
public List<Pessoa> listPessoas()
    {
        EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();

        Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Pessoa p");

        List<Pessoa> pessoas = null;
        pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>(q.getResultList());
        return pessoas;
    }
```

Is there another way to return data from the database?